# Remove a default compiler option when building with setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, pybind11

I am exposing my C++ code to Python using pybind11. Let's say I'm doing exactly [the example](https://github.com/pybind/python_example) provided by the pybind developers. In the end, I'm building using

```
python setup.py build
```

The compiler is invoked with

```
clang ... -DNDEBUG ... -O3 ... -I... -std=c++14
```

My question is simple:

*How can I, at least temporarily, switch on the assertions in my code? I.e. how can I tell the setuptools to omit the `-DNDEBUG` compiler option?*

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
setup(…
    ext_modules=[Extension(…
        undef_macros=['DEBUG']
    …)]
…)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This seems exactly what I need. Sadly though, it seems that it does not work for me... To verify that the option is actually invoked I also tried the illegal `undef_macros=['-DNDEBUG']` which raises indeed an error. Also `undef_macros=['DNDEBUG']` does not get rid of the define.

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `undef_macros=['NDEBUG']`?

Comment: Sorry, then I did not make myself clear enough. I tried `undef_macros=['NDEBUG']` in addition to what I mention. With each of them the compiler option `-DNDEBUG` remains.

Comment: You should inspect your command line more carefully. It seems to work on my machine. With undef_macros=['NDEBUG'] the setup script emits `clang ... -DNDEBUG ... -UNDEBUG ...`.  The  -U<NAME> effectively cancels prior define via -D<NAME>.